# Icono creado con flutter_launcher_icons tiene mucho padding

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, ese icono que he añadido utilizando flutter_launch_icons, tiene mucho paddingg, mi intención es que la imagen ocupe todo el circulo, o el "cuadracirculo" en caso de los móviles con versiones más recientes de android.

Aquí dejo el código que genera el icono

```
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_icons:
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path_android: "assets/IconoApp_cuadrado_1024.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/IconoApp_cuadrado_1024.png"
  #adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/IconoApp_cuadrado_1024.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
```

Los adaptative foreground y background los he ido comentando, porque no parecen generarse al ejecutar el comando. Una idea que se me ha ocurrido es poner en el background la imagen en si, y luego el "icono" que sea una imaggen transparente, pero esto no sirve para iOS porque no se pueden tener imággenes con Alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usar adaptive_icon_background, segun la documentación

> adaptive_icon_background: The color (E.g. "#ffffff") or image asset
> (E.g. "assets/images/christmas-background.png") which will be used to
> fill out the background of the adaptive icon.

```
flutter_icons:
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/background_icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/foreground_icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
```